# Discord.py custom emoji not sending correctly

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, emoji

I have tried a bunch of different strategies and none have made the bot say the wanted emote. (Or any emote at all.)

```
emoji = client.get_emoji(1234567890)
       await message.channel.send(emoji)

msg = "<:EmoteName:134567890>".format(client)
       await message.channel.send(msg.format(client))
```

They always produce :EmoteName:. It is in the server and has access to those emoji, etc.

Comment: "<:EmoteName:134567890>".format(client)        what should client be formatted instead of? https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

Comment: client = discord.Client()

- Is this what you want? It is formatted with the discord import

Comment: No. Look at the link. You have to specify where to insert the argument of .format(). It must be specified with {}. I don't see any couple of brackets in your string.

Comment: I don't think this helps me. I don't need to insert the emoji into text, I just need discord to send the emoji correctly.;
msg = "The emoji is {CustomEmoji}."
       await message.channel.send(msg.format(CustomEmoji = '<:EmoteName:134567890>'))

Just returns "The emoji is :JE:."

Comment: the .format() doesn't make sense, and if its a animated emoji its always an **a** before the **<** like this `<a:EmoteName:134567890>` so make sure you didn't miss that out too. The bot also needs to be in the same server where the emoji is stored at

Comment: I removed the .format()s and it still says :EmojiName:. I got that part too, it's not animated. As I said above it is in that server.

Comment: I meant exactly what @Rdimo said: you don't know how does .format() work.

Comment: So you are sure the bot has the access to the emoji? Are the intents enabled?

Comment: Intents are all on and the bot was invited with administrator. I just gave it a overriding emoji perm as well.

Comment: In this case I don't know what the problem may be, sorry. I hope you will catch it.

Comment: I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the emoji ID, it wasn't correct and I couldn't get the right one. All you need to do is put `\:EmoteName:` into discord and it will return the correct info.